# How can I indent all rows in a TableView except the first one?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to figure out how to indent every row in a section (tableView) after the first row. In the application it will look like this: First Row will be the date, the rest of the rows will all be indented and will hold some data corresponding to the date. I can figure out how to indent ALL the rows in a section; however, I don't want this. The first row should not be indented, every other row after the first row should be.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try [tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //get the reference of cell by dequeueing and do any configuration as required
    cell.indentationLevel = indexPath.row == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    cell.indentationWidth = 20.0; //or any width you like
    return cell;
}
```

Or you can just set the `indentationWidth` in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and implement `-tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return indexPath.row  == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually came across the documentation also and just adjusted the index.path - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( indexPath.section==TRAIL_MAP_SECTION && indexPath.row==0 ) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 1;
}